# PXE Setup for Xenial prepends squashfs path with /cdrom

Tags: 16.04, pxe, preseed, kickstart

I've tried everything I can think of, but I must be missing something.

I'm using a PXE setup that pulls everything from a web server to install 16.04.

The "default" file contains:

```
LABEL Ubuntu 16.04 Desktop
MENU LABEL Xenial 16.04 Desktop
KERNEL 1604/ubuntu-installer/amd64/linux
append vga=normal ks=http://192.168.1.251/ks-1604-64-desktop.cfg initrd=1604/ubuntu-installer/amd64/initrd.gz biosdevname=0 hostname=desktop
```

The KERNEL linked there is fed by TFTP and is an rsync mirror of the "network install" image from Ubuntu's website.  Both that and the actual install iso image were grabbed today.

My Kickstart file includes:

```
preseed --owner d-i live-installer/net-image string http://192.168.1.251/ubuntu-1604.amd64/install/filesystem.squashfs
```

But, when it hits the point in the installer where it grabs the filesystem.squashfs, it dies and logs this in syslog:

```
base-installer: info: Downloading /cdromhttp://192.168.1.251/ubuntu-1604.amd64/install/filesystem.squashfs to /tmp/live-installer/filesystem.squashfs
```

Which of course fails, because the url shouldn't be prepended with "/cdrom".  I can tell it's reading the path to the squashfs from the preseed line, but I don't have the word "cdrom" in any of my configuration files.

I've also tried adding the path as an append option, which works great for my 14.04 installs as in:

```
append vga=normal ks=http://192.168.1.251/ks-1404-64-desktop.cfg initrd=ubuntu-installer/amd64/initrd.gz live-installer/net-image=http://192.168.1.251/ubuntu.1404.amd64/install/filesystem.squashfs biosdevname=0 hostname=desktop
```

Any ideas of how to override this prepending of /cdrom for 16.04?

Comment: This looks like a bug to me, and I can't find a workaround.  I've filed a bug report at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/live-installer/+bug/1575652

Comment: Have a look into the similar issue. [ubuntu 16.04 pxe server install problem finding live-image](http://askubuntu.com/questions/781954/ubuntu-16-04-pxe-server-install-problem-finding-live-image/793097#793097) Follow the link for the step by step resolution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a workaround.
To edit fetch-url file, to trim /cdrom string in varable url. then repack initrd, everything looks fine. I just tested it. It is cool. Thanks Mengda's investigation together with me.

Comment: Can you provide the script changes you used?  I'm not a shell scripter, but I did extract the initrd file and found the fetch-url script.  What did you add?

Comment: Ah got it.  I used this guide to extract and rebuild the initrd.gz file:  http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/07/how-to-view-modify-and-recreate-initrd-img/  then I added these two lines just before the proto= line:   prefix="/cdrom"
url=${url#$prefix}